# How do I add a constant equation answer to display "hp" in my game?

Tags: python

I have been working on this game for quite a bit of time running into many problems. Though, recently I have run into one I do not know how to fix. I am quite new to Python, and coding in general, but I am trying to add an equation to my code so that it will display the health of my character and the dragon as they attack each other. I understand this code is horribly formatted and there are some errors, but could someone tell me how to create this constant equation? (Look at code down below for clarity).

```
import time
import sys
import random

print "Welcome to Scarlet Adventure, a text based game"

time.sleep(1.5)

print"Controls: Yes or No"

startQuestion = raw_input("Ready to start?")

def startGame():
time.sleep(0.75)
print"You wake up to darkness... You remember nothing."
time.sleep(2)
print"You get up, off the ground, your head aches!"
time.sleep(1.5)
print"You look around your surroundings, all it is, is forest. Until, your  eye catches a faint light. You squint hard and see a hazy building."
time.sleep(4)
print"You conclude it's a village."
time.sleep(1.5)

def p1():
p1 = raw_input("You can either go to the village and ask the people, or venture off into the woods. Would you like to go to the village?")
if p1 == "Yes":
section2()
if p1 == "No":
section3()

def section2():
time.sleep(0.5)
print"You get up and start walking to the village..."
time.sleep(1)
print "After about 30 minutes you reach village. Its much bigger than you  had expected. It seems to be a kingdom."
p2()

def section3():
print"You get up and start wandering around the forest. You see a shine.."
time.sleep(1.5)
print"Before you know it, 5 guards, in iron armour come out from behind a tree and run towards you. One of the yells out- Stop right there peasant! We're taking you to the Kingdom! -"
time.sleep(1.5)
p3()

def p2():
p2 = raw_input("You keep your head down and look at others. You recognize your clothes do not match the ones of the citizens. Would you like to get some new clothes?")
if p2 == "Yes":
section4()
if p2 == "No":
section8()

def p3():
p3 = raw_input("You can either run, or listen to the guards. Would you like to come with guards?")
if p3 == "Yes":
section5()
if p3 == "No":
section6()

def section4():
time.sleep(1)
print"You enter a shop with all different kinds of things."
time.sleep(1)
print"You see a beatiful blue leather tuic, as well as some grey pants. The tag says- $5 -for each."
p4()

def section5():
print"The guards take you to a prison cell and tell you that they will discuss the matter with the emperor. They give you some clothes to change into"
print"Another cell mate tells you that its not true. They never discuss your matters, you stay here forever."
p5()

def section6():
print "You run hard, as fast as you can. The leader of the guards yells- Fire! -A whistling sound becomes louder and louder until an arrow pierces your heart... You have died."
time.sleep(1)
lostGame()

def p4():
p4 = raw_input("You reach into your pocket and find $10. Would you like to buy them?")
if p4 == "Yes":
section7()
if p4 == "No":
section8()

def p5():
p5 = raw_input("You look on the ground and find a small piece of malleable metal. Must have come from the blacksmith nextdoor. Would you like to try to pick the lock?")
if p5 == "Yes":
section9()
if p5 == "No":
section10()

def section7():
print"You buy the clothes and look splendid. You walk around the town and see a poster. It talks about an evil beast, the prize of it's death is $10000!"
p6()

def section8():
print"People murmur about you and whisper. A guard sees you and instantly knows your from the outside. He runs at you and slices of your head, no intruders allowed!..."
lostGame()

def section9():
print"It worked! You slowly sneak out of the prison cell. You see the man that had told you about staying here forever. You open up his cell, and the two of you sneak out"
print"You walk around town in the clothes the guards gave you. With the corner of you eye you spot a poster. It talks about an evil beast, the prize of it's death is $10000!"
p6()

def section10():
print"You stay in the prison cell for another day, until a gurad comes by for cell inspection. He finds a piece of metal and accusing you of attempted escape. He beheads you..."
lostgame()

def p6():
p6 = raw_input("Would you like to go slay the evil beast?")
if p6 == "Yes":
adventureStart()
if p6 == "No":
section11()

def section11():
print"You stay in the kingdom and live there for the rest of your life. You own a small hut, with little to eat. You live somewhat happy..."
endGame()

def lostGame():
time.sleep(1.5)
lostGame = raw_input("You have lost the game. Would you like to start over?")
if lostGame == "Yes":
startGame()
if lostGame == "No":
print"Leaving Game"
time.sleep(0.5)
sys.exit

def adventureStart():
print"You walk to the kingdom castle, there you meet a group of knights. You tell them your request and they send you on your adventure..."
time.sleep(3)
print"You wake up and look around, your in a carriage with about 7 other men. You are dressed in iron armour. You must have fallen asleep!"
time.sleep(3)
print"After some hours you arrive at a large stone brick castle. Everyone moves out to enter. You follow them."
time.sleep(2)
print"Inside you see the corpses of knights, this must be a strong beast!"
time.sleep(1.5)
print"After walking some ways, you find a bridge. The men start to cross it, suddenly a small portion of the bridge in front crumbles! Two men fall down, to their death. Now only 5 remain."
time.sleep(3.5)
print"Everyone else crosses the bridge safely. Shortly after the bridge you come across a trap! 3 men fall for it and are killed by an arrow. Only you and one other remain."
time.sleep(3)
print"The other man flees!"
time.sleep(1)
print"After some time you finally come upon two gates, you open them and there it is, the Scarlet Dragon!"
fightOptions1()

def fightOptions1():
time.sleep(2)
print"Use key 1, 2, 3, & 4 for selecting your moves.."
fightOptions1 = raw_input("1. Sword Strike [10dmg - 10/10] 2. Wind Slice [25dmg - 1/1] 3. Jab [20dmg - 3/3]4. Flee [0dmg - infinite]")
if fightOptions1 == "1":
time.sleep(1.5)
print"You hit the dragon: -10 hp"
time.sleep(1.5)
dragonMove()
if fightOptions1 == "2":
time.sleep(1.5)
print"You hit the dragon: -25 hp"
dragonMove()
if fightOptions1 == "3":
time.sleep(1.5)
print"You hit the dragon: -20hp"
time.sleep(1.5)
dragonMove()
if fightOptions1 == "4":
time.sleep(1.5)
print"You cant flee! The dragon must be below 50hp."
time.sleep(1.5)
else:
print"Invalid move- try again."
fightOptions1()

def dragonMove():
L = 2
R = 3
C = 4
dodgeMove = random.randint(2, 4)
time.sleep(1.5)
dodgeChoice = raw_input("The Dragon is charging up! Choose: left (L), right (R), or center (C) to dodge the move!")
if dodgeChoice == dodgeMove:
print"The Dragon hit you: -25hp"
time.sleep(1.5)
else:
print"Good job! You successfully dodged the Dragon's move: -0hp"
time.sleep(1.5)
def endGame():
time.sleep(1.5)
print"Thank You for playing Scarlet Adventure."
time.sleep(1.5)
print"The End"
time.sleep(0.75)
print"Leaving Game"
time.sleep(0.5)
sys.exit
if startQuestion == "Yes":
fightOptions1()
```

Comment: Hmmm. What exactly do you want to do?  Not getting much clarity and your code is too long.   Something like "xxxx you wake up bla bla **your HP=15**".  Why not post only the combat sequences then?

Comment: When someone is attacked (lets say the attack does 40 dmg) I would like for the code to do something like 100 - x = current_hp and then display it. So in this case it would be: 100 - 40 = 60 ans the display would say. "Dragon attacked you with _________ you now have 60 hp!"

Comment: Like I said trim down your post a bit.  It's way down before anything shows up about combat.

Comment: Sorry I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming a global variable player_hp tracks current hp.

```
print ("The Dragon hit you!  Your HP=%(player_hp)s" % globals())
```

OK, to bring it down some more:

```
#global variable, can be shared between functions
player_hp = 200

def somefight():
    #ask stuff to do / resolve results - I'll just assume you got hit

    damage = 15 
                     #don't forget this global declaration
    global player_hp #need to refer to the variable outside of function
    #now update the variable outside of this function
    player_hp = player_hp - damage

    #grab the global variables.
    #this will result in a dictionary {"player_hp" : 185}
    the_variables = globals()

    #and now we merge in the local variables
    #{"player_hp" : 185, "damage" : 15}
    the_variables.update(locals())

    print "you got hit for %(damage)s and have now %(player_hp)s" % the_variables

    #                                               | 
    #                               will substitute in the value 
    #                               for the player_hp key in the 
    #                               the_variables dictionary
```

Comment: I am very sorry, but I do not understand this. Is it possible for you to break it down a little bit more? Thank You!

Comment: If it suits you, consider Accepting it.  That's the usual 'thank you' method, **if** it really solved your issue.